# I working on a project using Nuxt.js for my frontend and Nuxt.js for my backend

Tags: nuxt.js

[problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l3JrC.png) i have problem with my nuxt project when a run nmp run dev , its open website but some function wont works , I'm having trouble starting my app using npm start. When I try to run the application, I encounter a problem that I am not able to solve with certain. Here are the details of my problems, can someone pls help thanls u

```
import Joi from "joi";
import  {PrismaClient} from "@prisma/client"


const prisma = new PrismaClient()


const schema = Joi.object({
    make: Joi.string().required(),
    model: Joi.string().required(),
    year: Joi.number().min(1866).max(new Date().getFullYear() + 1),
    km: Joi.number().required().min(0),
    city: Joi.string().min(2).required(),
    numberOfSeats: Joi.number().max(1000).min(1).required(),
    description: Joi.string().min(20).required(),
    features: Joi.array().items(Joi.strin()).required(),
    image: Joi.string().required(),
    listerId: Joi.string().required(),
    price: Joi.number().min(0).required(),
    name: Joi.string().required(),

    
});



export  default defineEventHandler(async (event) => {
    const body = await redaBody(event);

    const { error, value } =  await schema.validate(body);

    const {
        image,
        name,
        numberOfSeats,
        km,
        price,
        features,
        description,
        listerId,
        city,
        make,
        model,

        
    }= body

    const car = await prisma.car.create({
        data: {
            image,
            name,
            numberOfSeats,
            km, parseInt(km),
            price, parseInt(price),
            features,
            description,
            listerId,
            city, city.toLowerCase(),
            make,
            model,

        }
    })







    return car;

    


});
```

Comment: You have the file and the line issue. Probably a syntax problem, follow the error tip. You could alternatively use ESlint to get some extra help.